# Store bokeh html file in shared location

Tags: bokeh

I have a bokeh html file that I would like to store in a central shared location. It is important that the file stays in the html format as it has tooltips etc that are key parts of the way the data is being visualised.

Ideally, I am hoping to have hyperlinks in an Excel spreadsheet that will point to the location of these bokeh files. My plan is to send out this spreadsheet to the relevant parties and they will be able to access the bokeh files through the hyperlinks.

I have tested putting the bokeh files in a OneDrive folder and then sharing this, but clicking on the hyperlink just effectively opens a text viewer which displays the html behind the bokeh.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the best solution was to use Github.

1. Create a repository called `[GITHUB_USERNAME].github.io`
2. Follow the instructions in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vASHVT0qKc)
3. Find the html files you uploaded at `https://[GITHUB_USERNAME].github.io/[FILE_NAME].html`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html code of a plot by using `file_html` and write the output to a file using standard Python operations.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

# add a circle renderer with a size, color, and alpha
p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)

# show the results
show(p)
html = file_html(p, CDN, "myplot")

outFile = open('/home/jasper/Dropbox/plot.html', 'w')
outFile.write(html)
outFile.close()
```